# Display .pdf doecument from folder in php

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

I want to display `.pdf` file in `codeigniter` using `mpdf`.

Iframe, object and embed tag is not working.

Scenario:

-click on button pdf file open in new tab. now if .jpg file then it is showing in pdf but if it is ".pdf" file not showing in that open pdf file.

Here is my PDF structure:-

```
        $body="";
        $this->load->library('mpdf/mpdf.php');
        $mpdf=new mPDF();
        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('real');
        $mpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);

        $body.=$this->load->view('test.php',$data,true);
        }
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($body);

        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

        $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; 

        $mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: did you try `$pdf = $mpdf->Output('mypdf.pdf','I');`?

Comment: share some code!! what you have done??

Comment: Yes I tried this but it's not working for me.